# Android- How to save Firebase Uid onto SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-sharedpreferences

After having the user log in and getting their uid, how would I save their uid onto SharedPreferences so I can access it throughout my project?
This is my code to get their uid:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            String userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
            String userEmail = firebaseUser.getEmail();
        } 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Try like this:***

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            String userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
            String userEmail = firebaseUser.getEmail();
            sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("firebasekey", userId);
            editor.commit();
        } 
    }
};
```

**To retrieve in other activity:**

```
        sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String UserId = sharedPref.getString("firebasekey", "");
```

Comment: whats the "" for after "firebasekey"?

Comment: Its a default value for String type. @Mozy

Comment: So what value should I put there?

Comment: Its like "KEY","VALUE". You can put any value.

Comment: I put in the value "0", but when I reference UserId, and save that file to Firebase, the file isnt the UserId but "0"?

Answer (score 3):

**Try like this**

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            String userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
            String userEmail = firebaseUser.getEmail();
            sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("firebasekey", userId);
            editor.commit();
        } 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to save your UID into `sharedpreference`.

```
// for saving uid for shared preference



FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            String userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
            String userEmail = firebaseUser.getEmail();
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_UID ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sp.edit().putInt(Save_UID,userId ).commit();
        } 
    }
};


// Retrieving id to any activity by calling this

SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_UID,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int sc  = sp.getInt(Save_UID,0);
```